# Not able to open the WSDL by using Soap UI

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

Not able to create a new project in Soap UI.
Getting the error msg: "there was something wrong with the wsdl you are trying to import soapui"

But able to open the WSDL in web browser.The WSDL is alive.When i opened the WSDL in web browser,getting the XML data.

URL format is: http://servername.com:1111/test.asmx?wsdl

Please help me out of this.

Comment: Error message says that WSDL is accessible but has some issues inside. You should verify your WSDL file instead of checking its accessibility. Opening WSDL in web browser just verifies that XML format of the file is well formed but it can have some invalid semantic issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the latest maintenance version (4.6.4-maintenance). It contains some fixes for fetching WSDLs that might fix your problem. It is available at http://www.soapui.org/Downloads/soapui-nightly-builds.html.